# Payroll Array Issues (unsure why calculations do not begin)

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

```
public struct pay
    {
        public string name;
        public int rate;
        public int hours;
        public int gross;
        public int wtd;
        public int ssd;
        public int md;
        public int net;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        pay[] myPay = new pay[3];
        for (int i = 0; i<= 2; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter name: ");
            myPay[i].name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter pay rate: ");
            myPay[i].rate = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter hours worked: ");
            myPay[i].hours = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Name\tRate\tHours\tGross\t W/T\tSS\tMed\tNet");
        for (int i = 0; i<=2; i++)
        {
            int gross = (myPay[i].rate * myPay[i].hours);
            int wtd = (myPay[i].gross * (1/20));
            int ssd = (myPay[i].gross * (3 / 100));
            int md = (myPay[i].gross * (1 / 100));
            int net = (myPay[i].gross - (md + ssd + wtd));
            Console.WriteLine(myPay[i].name + "\t" + myPay[i].rate + "\t" + myPay[i].hours + "\t" + myPay[i].gross + "\t" + myPay[i].wtd + "\t" + myPay[i].ssd + "\t" + myPay[i].md + "\t" + myPay[i].net);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The code is intended to take the name, rate, and hours worked of an employee to find gross pay. Then, costs will be taken from gross pay (each indicated with WTD, SD, and MD) to find the net income for the employee.

For whatever reason, the calculations for gross pay never begin, and therefore  the following calculations do not register either. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If they never begin, what happens instead? Side note: `1/20` will evaluate to 0 because you're working with integers and 0.05 is less than 1. In all situations, wtd, ssd, and md will evaluate to 0 because of this.

Comment: Can you show  what is the output of your program in console ?

Comment: What **exact** values you are typing into the console when you run this? What **exactly** happens when you run this code?

Comment: This would be an excellent time to learn to use a debugger. Stepping through the code line by line to see what's happening would help you solve this sort of problem pretty quickly on your own.

Comment: [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) is a beautiful thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a decimal value, you cant store it in an `int`

[int (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/int)

If you are going to be calculating money you need to use a `decimal`

[decimal (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal)

**Struct**

```
public struct pay
{
   public string name; 
   public int rate;  
   public int hours;    
   public decimal gross;    
   public decimal wtd;    
   public decimal ssd;    
   public decimal md;    
   public decimal net;

   public void Calculate()
   {
      gross = (rate * hours);
      wtd = (gross * (1 / (decimal)20));
      ssd = (gross * (3 / (decimal)100));
      md = (gross * (1 / (decimal)100));
      net = (gross - (md + ssd + wtd));
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   pay[] myPay = new pay[3];
   for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Enter name: ");
      myPay[i].name = Console.ReadLine();
      Console.WriteLine("Enter pay rate: ");
      myPay[i].rate = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
      Console.WriteLine("Enter hours worked: ");
      myPay[i].hours = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
   }

   Console.WriteLine("Name\tRate\tHours\tGross\t W/T\tSS\tMed\tNet");

   for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
   {
      myPay[i].Calculate();
      Console.WriteLine($"{myPay[i] .name}\t{myPay[i] .rate}\t{myPay[i] .hours}\t{myPay[i] .gross}\t{myPay[i] .wtd}\t{myPay[i] .ssd}\t{myPay[i] .md}\t{myPay[i] .net}");
   }
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**Output**

```
Enter name:
dfg
Enter pay rate:
4
Enter hours worked:
5
Enter name:
dh
Enter pay rate:
56
Enter hours worked:
7
Enter name:
fjh
Enter pay rate:
56
Enter hours worked:
4
Name    Rate    Hours   Gross    W/T    SS      Med     Net
dfg     4       5       20      1.00    0.60    0.20    18.20
dh      56      7       392     19.60   11.76   3.92    356.72
fjh     56      4       224     11.20   6.72    2.24    203.84
```

***Disclaimer***, i just fixed up the glaring problems, however i am not liable for anyone you maim or otherwise injure with this code

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is using int as a variable, you should use decimal variable when calculating salaries or anything that involves currency to have exact result.